# Evaluate symbolic expression with self-defined operations

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way to overwrite (or self-define) the operators in symbolic expressions?
So the expression is something like that:

```
f0, f1 = sp.symbols('f0, f1')
expr = f0, f1
>> f0 + f1
```

And now I want to use my own special add functionality like:

```
def my_add(a, b):
   return a^b
```

The expressions are results of matrix multiplications, so its not possible to simply write:

```
expr = f0 ^ f1
```

Comment: You can't override the operators but you can define a custom function that does what you want.

Comment: You'll find a way to do what you want with magic methods. Have a look at http://www.python-course.eu/python3_magic_methods.php : __add__ and __radd__ might help you.